# Java- Remove vowels from user input using nested for loop

Tags: java, arrays, replace, char, comparator

So I've seen this simple question and answer a few times and I just wanted to try a different way to solve it. 
My solution does work- it replaces every vowel with an empty char. 
However, I've been trying to figure out a way in my code where the char can be simply removed and not replaced with **empty char ' '**.

For example...
In my code, if the user inputted: happy, the result is h ppy

Although this does answer the question, I would like to also see the output: hppy

Hopefully, I can get some help, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        char [] vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u',
                            'A','E','I','O','U'};//char array


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter phrase: ");
        String phrase = in.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
                char ch = vowels[j];
                char ch2 = phrase.charAt(i);
                if (ch == ch2) {
                    phrase = phrase.replace(phrase.charAt(i), ' ');


                }

            }

        }
         System.out.println(phrase);
```

Comment: `phrase = phrase.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "")` would be easiest.

Comment: Please be aware that `phrase.replace` will replace all instances of one character with another. So if there are ten 'e's, the first call to replace will replace all ten, and you'll never see another 'e' later on.

Comment: An idiomatic manual solution (i.e. not using `replaceAll`) would involve a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), to copy all non-vowel characters into, followed by invoking `toString()` on it.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work: `phrase.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "")`

Comment: Yes, it does. However, this would defeat the purpose of my nested for loop. I was trying to basically iterate through each letter in the phrase and then compare it to each iteration of the declared char array named "vowels"... if there is a match, then replace that letter in the phrase

Comment: I see. Seems really complicated for what it is. If you are doing this to learn more about nested loops or strings, maybe another problem would be better suited?

Comment: could be complicated for what it is, I just wanted to look at solving it from a different perspective and see if it worked. thanks for helping!